# Jersey Client getting 403 running in Weblogic but ok stand alone

Tags: rest, jersey, weblogic

I've finished developing a Rest client project and started getting problems putting it to work integrated with the main application.

During the development I created a "main" method in a class just to make all the calls to save the time of deploying and all container stuff, but now I have to put it to work with the whole application in Weblogic and curiously the requests to the same service that works fine using a "main" method return an annoying "403 Forbidden".

The Weblogic is running local, the same machine I get my client project working using "main" method. **The main difference is that is not the same VM, when I get the 403 it is running inside Weblogic VM.**

I don`t have any clue about what is going on, I tried to find if there is any VM param I could configure/remove from Weblogic VM but didn`t find anything.

The last thing I tried was changing the Jersey Client implementation to use HttpUrlConnection to call the service, but the result was the same 403.

Here is an example using Jersey Client but I don`t think there is something wrong about it, it is quite the same you can find out there:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(CLIENT_URL);
String result = token = 
WebResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

Any tips for me? please ??

Comment: What type of authentication does the service use?

Comment: As far as I know, none! I tried to call the simplest service available, a GET call with no params using DHC plugin and it worked. Without any key or authentication-header.

Answer (score 0):

My bad guys.

In the end the problem was inside the main Application, due to networking issues there is a property file with a list of URLs we are supposed to use proxy to have access, as it is controlled within the main application I was told to add the service URL in the file and now everything is working fine.